# System.RegularExpressions replace space

Tags: regex, string, delphi, replace, delphi-xe4

I have a string I am parsing with static `Replace` as in using this:
`class function Replace(const Input, Pattern, Replacement: string): string; overload; static;`

my string is very simple: `-c ABCDE -l 3` and I'm trying to replace `-c` or `/c:` or `/c=` or different possible commandline paramaters.  Results should be `ABCDE 3` or whatever `value`.

my function is so:  `P := regexpr.Replace(Arg,'(?i)(-|/|--)(c|l)(\s|:|=)', '');`

`P` and `Arg` are `string` variables.

Replacement pattern is `nothing`. As in `''`

I also tried `(?i)(-|/|--)(c|l)(\s*|:|=)` to match more spaces but in complied application 
it doesn't work.

this works but doesn't handle spaces `P := regexpr.Replace(Arg,'(?i)(-|/|--)(c|l)(:|=)', '');`

This part: `(?i)` for case insensitive.

This part: `(-|/|--)` similar to TSysCharSet characters but takes 2 characters at a time as in `--` part in expression.

This part: `(c|l)` for looking at my character to specify `Value`.

This part: `(:|=)` specifying to use either `:` or `=` after my character and before `Value`

How do I add `Space` to that? I tried `\s` also `\x20` and `[ ]`. I also tried with character such as `c:(\s)` for more spaces than one: `\s*` none worked so far as `P = -c` after replacement.

BTW this expression works on RegexBuddy as it supposed to.

**EDIT1:**
I am replacing:
`-c, --c, /c, /C, --C, :, =, /x20, -l, --l, --L, etc...`

cmd line is:
`-c ABCDE -l 3`
what i have after replace is `ABCDE` and `3`

**EDIT2:**
As Rob Kennedy pointed out in comment below `Arg` doesn't have the correct string as it chokes on spaces. I used `ParamCount` to iterate through commands. I guess I have to parse the whole line without `ParamCount`. Answer below is a good expression and points out to a nice site too.

**EDIT3:**
the expression was `(?i)[-\/]+(c|l)[:=\s]*` that works for multiple spaces as well.
Moral of the story: `ParamStr` and `ParamCount` are good tools but do not account for all possible scenarios. better to use `cmdLine` for the whole string and parse it manually.

Comment: Is it possible that `Arg` comes from calling `ParamStr`? That function splits arguments on spaces already, so you're unlikely to get a space in the first place. That could explain why your test passes, but not your real code. In other words, are you *sure* `Arg` really contains a space for you to detect?

Comment: you are very right. Arg chokes on space from command line. `Arg :- -c`how did I miss this :(

Comment: To have spaces in arguments, quote them. But you don't want that. You need to conditionally read the *next* argument if it wasn't included in the argument you've already seen. The alternative is to parse `CmdLine` yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Delphi [mimics the regular expression classes in the .NET framework](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html), in order to match:

- `-c`
- `/c:`
- `/c=`
- `/l`
- `/l=`
- `--c AGBCDE` (capturing `--c` without `AGBCDE`)

Use: `(?i)[-\/]+(c|l)[:=\s]?`

You can see a working example here: http://regex101.com/r/rS3bD7

Comment: It doesn't match `space` between `C` and `value` for example: `--c ABCDE`

Comment: Probably best to make a list of what you want it to match then ;)

Comment: My current expression matches everything I want except for that space between `-c` and `value` such as string I posted for example like `ABCDE`. Try this: `-c ABCDE` I want result to be `ABCDE`

Comment: So you want to remove ABCDE as well? Or just strip -c[space] and leave ABCDE behind? (In which case I updated the expression and the example link to do that).

Comment: I also replaced the capture groups you had in there with character classes, which marginally reduce the processing time of the expression.

Comment: No I want all that remain is `ABCDE` and `3` from the example I gave. So start with `-c ABCDE -l 3` and with Regex we have `ABCDE` and `3` remaining.

Comment: so this works on browser but not in delphi xe4. I tried this expression on RegexBuddy and it works but not in Delphi program. see this: `(?i)(-|\/|--)(c|l)(\s*|:|=)` works in browser but not delphi

Comment: OK, so part of the problem is that your original question doesn't state anything about multiple arguments; please update your question with a bulleted list of ALL possible matches and results. Moreover, the expression I changed it to recently *will* actually remove -c[space] and -l[space] from your example there, so next step is to get it working in Delphi.

Comment: My fault for not seeing that `ParamCount[i]` returned a part of the string not the whole string. I do like your expression better than mine though.

Comment: Ah! Good stuff. Good luck then!